# Creating multiple columns by different functions of different variables

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble transitioning to `data.table`.  I am trying to group by some categorical variables, and apply a list of functions that each target different variables in order to create new columns.  This is something that seems like it should be easy with `mapply` or `Map`, but I can't figure out to assemble the proper subset in the to pass to the functions.

Here is what it looks like,

```
set.seed(2015)
dat <- data.table(cat1 = factor('Total'),
                  cat2 = factor(rep(letters[1:4], 5)),
                  cat3 = factor(rep(1:4, each=5)),
                  var1 = sample(20),
                  var2 = sample(20),
                  var3 = sample(20))

## I have list of factor columns to group by
groups <- c(paste0("cat", 1:3))
setkeyv(dat, groups)

## List of functions, and corresponding list of column names that
## they are to be applied to.  So, in this example I should get
## two new columns: V1=sum(var1) and V2=mean(var2, var3)
thing <- function(...) mean(c(...), na.rm=TRUE)  # arbitrary function
funs <- list("sum", "thing")                     # named functions
targets <- list("var1", c("var2", "var3"))       # variables
outnames <- funs                                 # names or result columns

## Can't get this part
f <- function(fn, vars) do.call(fn, vars)
dat[, outnames := Map(f, funs, targets), by=groups]
```

The result for this example should be like this

```
dat[, `:=`(sum=sum(var1), thing=thing(var2, var3)), by=groups]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to subset the dataset columns based on the column names in the 'targets' `list`.  One way would to loop through the `list` elements of 'targets' and subset the data.table (`.SD[, x, with=FALSE]`), and then apply the function.

```
dat[, unlist(outnames) := Map(f, funs, lapply(targets, function(x)
                          .SD[, ..x])), by = groups]
```

Comment: great, looks good, I might have a follow up question in a bit, since I also need to be subsetting by indices at the same time.  Thanks!